# Qgis Python console not working

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I have a small problem with the Python console in Qgis. I am working through some code .py but lately the console does not show results, for example I write directly on the cosola

```
print "prueba"
```

*Enter* and it shows nothing, what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: is this qgis3? if so you must use python3 so print("prueba")

Comment: I have qgis 2.18

Comment: 2.18 is End of Life, please consider upgrading to 3.4

Comment: Yes it happens. You need just to close the project and reopen it and this should work fine.